# CucumberException : Failed to create scenario runner

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, pom.xml, cucumber-junit

When I try to run my scenario outline, I get this error - CucumberException : Failed to create scenario runner.

The same scenario outline was running successfully a few days back, but now I get this error.

I looked up this error online and found many posts suggesting it happens when using junit 4.12. But I am using junit 4.11, and I still get the same.

Here are my pom dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This is the Cucumber code :

```
Scenario Outline: Google search on different browsers
Given user opens google using <Browser>
When user searches for "Hello World"
Then user sees the results

Examples:
| Browser           |
| FireFox           |
| Internet Explorer |
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The problem is cucumber-junit version 1.1.8.

Change it to version 1.2.2 which should be compatible

Answer (score 0):

Could you also provide your cucumber code? I doubt that this has anything to do with JUnit 4.12

Comment: I would look for the issue in your version control system and see what changed compared to a few days ago. Whatever the change was, it is likely that the change caused the problem.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg I tried that, it is still not working. This is weird.

Comment: If you reverted everything to a point in time when it worked and it still doesn't work it is weird. Then there is something out of your control that has changed.

Comment: Not really an answer.  Post could be improved by moving to a comment on the question.